# How to read a base64 numerical vector from an XML file?

Tags: xml, r, base64

I am trying to read the Ydata from an XML file. The Base64 string containing the Ydata is a 1245-elements numerical vector and is stored in data$ATR. The file has been encoded according to the gaml.org standards.

Tried too many things the whole day, but none is working... Will not post here all the countless things I tried and that does not work. I am out of ideas. How to convert it to R numeric vector?

```
library(XML)
x = XML::xmlTreeParse("http://utsav.podzone.net/T0011VAP1.0.xml")
xmltop = xmlRoot(x)
data = xmlSApply(xmltop, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
(data$ATR)
```

From an independent source, I know that the first 10 elemens of Ydata are :

```
-0.0903
-0.0751
-0.0605
-0.0471
-0.0353
-0.0249
-0.0159
-0.0082
-0.0017
 0.0035
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is one ugly file ;-) It looks to be output from [these guys](https://www.bruker.com/products/infrared-near-infrared-and-raman-spectroscopy/opus-spectroscopy-software.html).

Using the `numvalues` from this XML tag in the data file:

```
<values byteorder="INTEL" format="FLOAT32" numvalues="1245">
```

if you do:

```
library(base64enc)

head(readBin(base64decode(data$ATR), "double", 1245, 4), 10)
```

I made the assumption that the `1245` for `numvalues` as the number of floating point #'s in the binary field—which turned out to be a good assumption.

it gives:

```
## [1] -0.090307593 -0.075070500 -0.060486197 -0.047122478 -0.035274029 -0.024934530 -0.015949965 -0.008214951
## [9] -0.001725793  0.003505349
```

That output tracks nicely with your 10 known elements.

The `readBin` call says to use `double` as the mode (data type) for the vector it's returning and the `4` is the # of bytes per element.

You may have to add `endian="little"` as a parameter to `readBin` depending on your architecture (at least I think that might be the case…I found `readBin` to be less than deterministic per-OS when using it to read color swatch files but I'm sure the CRAN guaRdians would berate me for questioning the behavior of it).

Comment: curious as to whether this helped solve your problem

Comment: yes! thanks hrbrmstr... But the library is not base64decode, it is base64enc. Right?

Answer (score 0):

I dont have access to that URL (company filtering), but this example may help:

The actual sample XML is

```
<root>
<value>123</value>
<value>234</value>
<value>345</value>
</root>
```

encoded as

```
PHJvb3Q+DQo8dmFsdWU+MTIzPC92YWx1ZT4NCjx2YWx1ZT4yMzQ8L3ZhbHVlPg0KPHZhbHVlPjM0NTwvdmFsdWU+DQo8L3Jvb3Q+
```

and the code to access the XML:

```
library("RCurl")
library("XML")
tmp <- "PHJvb3Q+DQo8dmFsdWU+MTIzPC92YWx1ZT4NCjx2YWx1ZT4yMzQ8L3ZhbHVlPg0KPHZhbHVlPjM0NTwvdmFsdWU+DQo8L3Jvb3Q+";
xml <- base64(tmp, encode=FALSE)

x = XML::xmlTreeParse(xml)
xmltop = xmlRoot(x)
data = xmlSApply(xmltop, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
```

Comment: Nice example, but it, unfortunately this does virtually nothing to help the OP.

Comment: thanks rbm, trying to answer without even having acces to the data. looks like hrbrmstr solved it :)